# PHP check if value even or odd?

Tags: php, if-statement

How to check if a value is even or odd?

```
while ($N=0 > 6; ++$N) { // might be mistake here but it just here for demonstration my cod differs
    ++$CELL;
    echo ($CELL/3)." - ";
    if(($CELL/3) % 2) {                        
        echo ($CELL/3)." (odd) <br>";
    } else {
        echo ($CELL/3)." (even) <br>";    
        echo "<tr>";
        };

   };
```

Can someone explain why it keeps outputing

```
0.333333333333 - 0.333333333333 (even)
0.666666666667 - 0.666666666667 (even)
1 - 1 (odd)
1.33333333333 - 1.33333333333 (odd)
1.66666666667 - 1.66666666667 (odd)
2 - 2 (even)
```

should not it be

```
0.333333333333 - 0.333333333333 (even)
0.666666666667 - 0.666666666667 (even)
1 - 1 (odd)
1.33333333333 - 1.33333333333 (even)
1.66666666667 - 1.66666666667 (even)
2 - 2 (odd)
```

kind of messed up even and odd but its not the point... is there better way to check if value is even?

Comment: Are you trying to check if decimal numbers are odd or even? Looks like odd and even only apply to integers. Based on your example, you are more likely checking if it's float or integer.

Answer (score 6):

if your intent is for *every third row* to be "odd" as per your example, then you need:

```
if ($N % 3 == 2) {
   // odd
} else {
   // even
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is much easy with this code

```
 while ($N=0 $N > 6; $N++) {
        if ($N%2==0){
          echo 'Value is even';
       } else {
          echo 'value is odd';
       }

    }
```

Comment: This does not give the desired results. Totally the asker's fault though.

Comment: As the question is not much clear it is just our guess what he actually wants. Question description says something else and Example says something else

Answer (score 1):

> "kind of messed up even and odd"

You, my friend, are the king of understatement.

If you want to check if a number **has no fractional component** then you need to convert it to an integer and compare it with the original.

```
$v = 3.4;
if ($v == (int)$v) {
  echo "Integer";
} else {
  echo "Fractional";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want it to round up before you check if it's even or odd. use the function ceil to round it up.

```
if(ceil($CELL/3) % 2) {                        
        echo ($CELL/3)." (odd) <br>";
    } else {
        echo ($CELL/3)." (even) <br>";    
        echo "<tr>";
        };
```

but 2 is definitely an even number

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does not make sense to check if a fractional number is odd or even. 
A number is **even** when that number modulo 2 is 0. 
For instance, if you divide any fractional number by 2 it will always be odd, just because if you divide that number by 2 you do not have an exact result.

So, please let us know what are you tring to do here so we can help you better

Comment: okay lets say i need to do certain action every 3rd step of a loop e.g. 3,6,9,12,... 900, 903 etc   
maybee i need to check if number is how to say it full not have  any decimals, how can i do it.  so i can devide by 3 and see if number is full its every third step then.

Comment: Mmm, if you need yo do an action avery 3 steps you can do something like this: if( ($i % 3) == 0 ) and inside this test block do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

> Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0):

use `%` (mod) operator.

```
for($N=0 $N > 6; $N++) { 
     ($N%2)? echo 'Value is even'; :  echo 'value is odd';
}
```